# Proof of an inequality using Cauchy's inequality: $\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k+\frac{1}{p_k}\right)^2\geq n^3+2n+\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: inequality

Given that $p_k> 0$ and $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n=1$, prove that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k+\frac{1}{p_k}\right)^2\geq
n^3+2n+\frac{1}{n}.
\end{equation}

I believe that Cauchy's inequality should be used at some point but I haven't figured out how. Expanding the square on the left-hand side gives $2n$ immediately, but I have problem producing the cubic term and $\frac{1}{n}$. Could anyone please offer some insight? It is ok to use any method, not necessarily Cauchy's inequality.

Comment: The minimum of the left hand side occurs when all $p_k$ are equal so $p_k = 1/n$ and the sum becomes $n\cdot(n + 1/n)^2 = n^3 + 2n + \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Jensen's Inequality instead of Cauchy's Inequality?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes. Any method should be ok.

Comment: @Winther Good point! Could you please suggest a way to justify that minimality can be achieved by forcing all $p_k$ equal?

Comment: We can 'justify' it from it being a symmetric problem and symmetric problems usually have symmetric solutions. As for proving it, a common way to do it is to use the powerful (but maybe not so elegant) method of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: $p=3, q=\frac {3}{2}, x_k=(p_k)^{\frac {2}{3}}, y_k=(p_k)^{-\frac {2}{3}}$ Answer to the comment on my answer.

Comment: @Winther Nice explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: @S.C.B. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2 = x^2+2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}$. Then, $f''(x) = 2+\dfrac{6}{x^4} > 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Since $f$ is convex on $[0,1]$, for any $p_1,\ldots,p_n \in [0,1]$ where $p_1+\cdots+p_n = 1$, we can use [Jensen's Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JensensInequality.html) to get $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}f(p_k) \ge f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}p_k\right)$$ $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left(p_k+\dfrac{1}{p_k}\right)^2 \ge f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$ $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left(p_k+\dfrac{1}{p_k}\right)^2 \ge nf\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) = n^3+2n+\dfrac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 10):

Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k+\frac{1}{p_k}\right)^2 =\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2+2n+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k^2}$$

Now note that $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1\right) \ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\right)^2 \implies \sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2 \ge \frac{1}{n} $$$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k^2}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\right) \ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1\right)^3  
\implies \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k^2} \ge n^3$$

From [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality).

Adding these two inequalities, we are done.

Comment: https://hcmop.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/holders-inequality/

Comment: Could you please point out the choice of $p$ and $q$ in Hölder's inequality? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k+\frac{1}{p_k}\right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k^2 + \frac{1}{p_k^2}+2\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k^2}+2n\,$. By [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean):

- $\;\;\sqrt{\cfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2} \;\ge\; \cfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n p_k = \cfrac{1}{n} \quad\implies\quad \sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2 \;\ge\; \cfrac{1}{n}$
- $\;\;\sqrt{\cfrac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n \cfrac{1}{p_k^2}}} \;\le\; \cfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n p_k = \cfrac{1}{n} \quad\implies\quad \sum_{k=1}^n \cfrac{1}{p_k^2} \ge n^3$

Adding up the above gives the stated inequality and, since it's all based on AM-GM, the equality holds iff all $p_k$ are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The question is from chapter 1 of J. Michael Steele's book ``The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class''. I didn't know that the book has solutions at the back. Below is the author's solution, which only employs Cauchy's inequality.

First, we expand the square.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k+\frac{1}{p_k}\right)^2 = 
\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2 + 2n + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k^2}.
\end{equation}

Consider the first sum. Notice that
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2 \right)
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1\right) \geq
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\right)^2=1,
\end{equation}
from which we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n p_k^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}.
\end{equation}

Now, consider the second sum, for which we first consider the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k}$. Observe that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{p_k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{p_k}} \leq
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} 
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{equation}
It follows that 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} \geq n^2.
\end{equation}

Next, we can obtain a lower bound for $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k^2}$. By Cauchy's inequality,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k} 1 \leq
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \geq
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k} \geq n^2.
\end{equation}
Squaring both sides, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k^2}\right) n \geq n^4.
\end{equation}
Therefore, 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k^2} \geq n^3.
\end{equation}

The conclusion that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k+\frac{1}{p_k}\right)^2 \geq
n^3 + 2n + \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}
follows.